# lifetime of a temporary shared_ptr object

Tags: c++

On one hand, in general, a temporary object is destroyed at the end of the full-expression that it is part of.

To quote the draft of the standard N4140 Section 12.2:

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

On the other hand, consider Case 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::shared_ptr;

void process(shared_ptr<int> p)
{
    std::cout << p.use_count() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    process(shared_ptr<int>(new int));
    return 0;
}
```

Or even simpler, as in Case 2

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::shared_ptr;

int main()
{
    cout << shared_ptr<int>(shared_ptr<int>(new int)).use_count() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In either case, the output is 1. Not 2.

I feel somewhat confused at the output, and appreciate anyone who may offer some explanation.

My understanding for Case 1 is that `shared_ptr<int>(new int)` is a temporary object passed to `process` as an argument. According to the standard, it should not be destroyed before `process` makes its return. If that were the case, then the parameter `p`, which is initialized from the temporary, should have a `use_count` of 2 at the time of output, because at that time there are 2 objects managed by the `shared_ptr`.

My understanding for Case 2 follows the same logic.

It seems that there must be some mistakes in my understanding. Could someone please point them out? Thanks very much.

*Note: There are several solved questions related to mine, but after reading them I am still confused. You may read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920659/shared-ptr-and-use-count) for your reference.*

Comment: Google search: copy elision.

Comment: it's not that, the argument can bind to &&, a copy is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `shared_ptr<int>(shared_ptr<int>(new int))` only creates one temporary, it is equivalent to `shared_ptr<int>(new int)`.

You can see what you expect using this code:

```
shared_ptr<int> f(shared_ptr<int>&& x){return x;}
int main()
{
    //N1:
    cout << shared_ptr<int>(f(shared_ptr<int>(new int))).use_count() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Following user1095108 proposal:

```
shared_ptr<int> f(shared_ptr<int>&& x){return x;}
int main()
{
    //also prints 2, because equivalent to N1
    cout << f(shared_ptr<int>(new int)).use_count() << endl;

    //prints 3:
    cout << shared_ptr<int>(f(f(shared_ptr<int>(new int)))).use_count() << endl;

    //also prints 3:
    cout << f(f(shared_ptr<int>(new int))).use_count() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nest one more level further for greater educational effect!

Comment: Great thanks for the demonstration! It becomes clear now. The last print statement may have an excessive `)` there :)